# Unable to call Firefox extension function from page Javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, dom-events

I have an XUL extension with different document object, perhaps that is why the following doesn't work:

In my page Javascript:

```
var evt = document.createEvent("Events");
evt.initEvent("JSON_UPDATE_EVENT", true, false);
document.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

In extension, the main.js file:

```
document.addEventListener("JSON_UPDATE_EVENT", alert("hello"), false, true);
```

I even tried tried:

```
Application.activeWindow.activeTab.document.addEventListener("JSON_UPDATE_EVENT", alert("hello"), false, true);
```

In both the cases the `alert()` is called only once when the extension is started, but never on the event. The document in web page and extension refer to different objects, that might be the reason perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the main.js file do this:

```
var chromeWindow = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser');
function rawr() { 
chromeWindow.alert("hello")
}
chromeWindow.gBrowser.addEventListener("JSON_UPDATE_EVENT", rawr, false, true);
```

each window with tabs has its own gBrowser.

if you want to add this to all currently open windows, and all future windows that open see this template here:
https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/8673632

use the template and just edit inside addDiv and removeDiv

Comment: Thanks a ton! I had tried everything including postmessage, chrome messaging etc. but nothing worked, but your solution worked out of the box.